# How to overlay an animated GIF onto a JPEG to get a composite gif file using overlay transformation to all frames at once

Tags: android, animated-gif

In an Android app, I need to overlay an animated GIF (with transparency) onto a JPEG file of same dimensions to get a composite gif file. I am hoping for something that can apply an overlay transformation to all frames at once, making it fast. Decomposing the gif and overlaying jpeg on all frames and then recomposing is very slow, and creates a huge file size of output gif. Thanks for the help...